# Calculate Profit Based on First-In, First-Out Pricing By Date Of Sale

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2008

How can I find the sales margin every Day via SQL, assuming they are sold in the order they were purchased? 
[image]

Comment: too many sql versions... do you want us to guess?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu the tag says sql-server-2008

Comment: thanks @Aaron ... you forgot to mention postgres and access-vba

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: And without even a hint of trying anything this comes across as "here is some data, do the work for me".

Comment: Are you guys going to post an hourly rate on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this solution -

```
;with cte as 
(
select purchase_date,item,cost, qty as num from purchase
union all
select purchase_date,item,cost, num-1 from cte where num>1
), 
cte2 as
(
select sale_date,item,price, qty as num from sales
union all
select sale_date,item,price, num-1 from cte2 where num>1
)

select sale_date, sum(price-cost) from (

(select sale_date, item, price ,row_number() over (order by sale_date,num) rn from cte2) s
inner join
 (select purchase_date, item, cost ,row_number() over (order by purchase_date,num) rn2 from cte) z
 on s.item=z.item and s.rn=z.rn2)
```

group by sale_date

Comment: many thanks i am tried run this solution in sql express 2005 appear this msg: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 's.sale_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.